# setting background-color in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a jQuery that if the value is 130 the color of the background.

Here is my code so far:

```
function Compute(p, m, f, studno) {
  var average;
  average = parseFloat(p * 0.3) + parseFloat(m * 0.3) + parseFloat(f * 0.4);
  $("#average_" + studno).val(average.toFixed());                           
  if($(this).text()=="130"){
    color:red           
  }       
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot better if you could edit your answer and format the code to be more readable. Look into the help when editing to find out how.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead - `$(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');`:

```
function Compute(p, m, f, studno) {
     var average;
     average = parseFloat(p * 0.3) + parseFloat(m * 0.3) + parseFloat(f * 0.4);
     $("#average_" + studno).val(average.toFixed());                            
     if($(this).text()=="130"){
       $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');           
     }        
}
```

Comment: you need to use backgroundColor instead as it is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the call to the function Compute, is not based on object, EX: you might have calling the Compute function not on any ID or class $('#someID/Class').Compute(....);, hence you will not get the value of $(this) keyword inside the function. So either way you have to use jquery plugin approach, OR since you have said in your question, that to change the color when value is 130, considering if the element is , then use $(this).val() instead of $(this).text(), if element is  then use $(this).html() instead of $(this).text().

Answer (score -1):

To change the background color in jQuery, you have to change the line "color:red" in your code by:

```
jQuery(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```